# How to customize the email in "request change" under the approval workflow SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Can the email that is sent to notify users of a 'Change Request' be edited?

I don't see an option in the approval process SharePoint 2010

Comment: Are you using Start an Approval activity in SharePoint Designer?

Comment: yes, i am using it

Comment: Any news on this problem ? I can't find where to edit the email sent by a change request...

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem previously and I searched the whole net back and forth and found nothing.

Finally I got this worked using workflow variables:

**Step1**

Go to the Task behaviors

Go to the When the Task is Pending:

then Email task notification to Current Task Assigned To

Yes I know this is only for the Task that we use for approval.

**Here is the magic:**

Do not put customized greetings such as please approve this and that.

Put only this:

[%Variable: NotificationMessage%]

If you dont know how to put the above variant:

*Add or Change Lookup then select Workflow Variables and Parameters for Data source ,
Then select NotificationMessage for Field from source)*

You can put a customized link under the variant if you want. Please note that the customized text will appear in every task ( Approval and change request as well ) so I only put information here that is relevant for all Tasks. Such as:
*Please review and take action in order to proceed etc etc...*
When you finished with this Hit OK

**Step2**

Go back to this point (When a Task is Pending)

Put a condition above all the others:

*If Current Task:Title begins with A change has been requested
Set variable: NotificationMessage to "Put whatever you want to display to the change request email body"*

Put another condition as a second just right below that we just created

*If Current Task:Title does not begin with A change has been requested
Set variable: NotificationMessage to "Put whatever you want to display to the Approvers"*

If you follow the above you`ll have customized notifications for the Approver tasks and the change request Tasks as well.

Publish the WF and enjoy ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the Start Approval Activity. Then from there you can see

"Change the behavior of a single task"
"Change the behavior of the overall task process"

You can click on those where you can see the "Send Email" activities.

Click on Send Email Activity for editing the Email Subject/Body etc.

Comment: Yes it works for  email for all tasks, but not for email in a case of using buttin request change. the body for this email text hidden somewhere

Comment: Click Change the behavior of a single task. In the "when a task is pending" section, click the first "email task notification to..."

Comment: No, in pending section there are no email body for change request message.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can customize the email using below steps in the image in "When a task is pending section".

1) First send the normal email when a item is created (Hence the check "Created"== "Modified").

2) Next when the user click on request change then you can check it by checking the email title "A change has been requested", also you can perform any activity like changing the status to "Need Clarification".

3) when user clarifies then it enters in the second else where you can customize the email and set to status back to "Submitted".

Let me know if there are any concerns.

Answer (score 0):

I was thrown at this question myself and the request was even more detailed to send a separate email after the response sent saying **"Your request for more information was provided by XXX"** and also pass on the comments requestor made to responder and vice versa. Same with reassign task **"XXX person reassigned the task for you"**.

Here are the comments etc. Also I had reminders set to go out with unique emails of course. So I needed to come up with more flexible approach than all the people mentioned in the above statement.

So [this](https://myshareforsharepoint.blogspot.com/2016/03/sharepoint-workflow-unique-email-for.html) link is my comprehensive solution by customizing the InfoPath by adding rules to see what is clicked and based on that sending emails.

Answer (score 0):

For single tasks use this condition on start
[image]